# Reading JSON from file in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, google-chrome-app

I am able to read the json content from file in chrome app but i want the returned json content in $scope.somevar. If i try to initialize $scope.somevar inside method, it goes out of scope.

```
SearchApp.controller("MyTagsApp", function($scope) {
    var myFile = '';
    chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
            root.getFile("MY_FILE.json", {}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(e) {

                        myFile = JSON.parse(this.result);
                        $scope.somevar = JSON.parse(this.result);
                        console.log(myFile);
                });
            });
        });
        console.log($scope.somevar); });
```

the last line returns ***undefined***. Being new to the angular technology, i am unable to understand where the issue is.

I am also trying to display the content on HTML page

```
<ul ng-repeat="i in somevar | filter: searchKeyword">
    <li>{{i.items.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

No Response.

Comment: one of your functions is an asynchronous callback (a Promise?), the outer `console.log` is executed **before** you get your JSON file

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($scope.somevar);
```

on the last line is executed earlier so the `$scope.somevar` is not initialized yet. Why are you trying to dump the contents anyway? The JSON content will be eventually accessible in the scope. If you need to do something with that result do it inside the anonymous function.

Comment: Should the content be displayed in web page then?

Comment: If the reading part is done right it will as soon as it is available to the scope.